# How to Give dynamic column name to @Query

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Here is the method in my repository Interface.

```
 @Query("select ?1 ,count(re) from Tabre group by ?1")                 
Page<RequestEntity> getGroupByColumnName(String columnName, Pageable pageable);
```

I would like to give column name dynamically to the query as mentioned above. But I see below error
error :

> "I see Parameters are only supported in SELECT clauses when used as
> part of a INSERT INTO DML statement".

I tried with single quotes, #{#columnName} with no luck.
Can someone help me on how to give the column name dynamically to the `@query`

Comment: it is not possible in jpa. for that you have to build the query by concatinating strings

Comment: It is possible, just not with spring in this manner. You instead would use JPA criteria to programmatically build dynamic queries (ensuring type safety and possible injection vectors). Spring has tie ins with its Specifications feature